# C programming iteration through arrays

Tags: c

[image: Problem statement]

How can I solve this?
This problem requires basic C array knowledge.
I have tried everything within my limited coding repertoire.
How can I let three variables equal each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies where you are taking input for the first index but not for the other two(1,2). Just replace this code and it will work:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     const int NUM_GUESSES = 3;
     int userGUESSES[NUM_GUESSES];
     int i=0;

     for(i=0; i<NUM_GUESSES; i++)
     {
         scanf("%d", &userGUESSES[i]);
     }

     for(i=0; i<NUM_GUESSES; i++)
     {
         printf("%d", userGUESSES[i]);
     }

     return 0;
}
```